# Entity Framework 4.1 - Segregating an entity into multiple tables (Code-First)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I'm trying to find out how I can re-use a simple 'Comment' entity type for multiple scenarios where something is 'commentable' in my application.

At the moment, I have a couple of entities that a user is able to post comments to.  Examples include Blogs, Profiles and Photos - these can all be 'commented' on.

I'd like to be able to use the same 'Comment' class for each of these scenarios, but I don't want to end up with one HUGE table full of comments for everything.  I figure it would be much more efficient to at least store a table of BlogComments, PhotoComments, and ProfileComments.  At the moment, my Comment class looks like this:

```
public class Comment
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int ContextId { get; set; }

   [StringLength(256)]
   public string Content { get; set; }

   public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }

   public virtual Member Author { get; set; }
}
```

Presumably, I'd need the 'ContextId' field to refer to the particular thing being commented on.  This Id might be the Id of a Blog, a Profile or a Photo.  I was hoping to be able to refer to comments much like a normal ICollection in these classes, and I have some code like this for the Photos as an example:

```
public class Photo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(48)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public virtual Member Owner { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

I've been pointed to various articles during my searches, but none really seem relevant to my particular situation.  How can I map these comment collections to different tables, and avoid having a comment "super-table"?

Any help, pointers or advice would be hugely appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an abstract `Comment` class and inherit from it specific comments such as `PhotoComment`, `ProfileComment`. You will be able to map the comments to different tables.

```
public abstract class Comment
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [StringLength(256)]
   public string Content { get; set; }

   public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }

   public virtual Member Author { get; set; }
}


public class PhotoComment : Comment
{
   public int PhotoId { get; set; }

   public virtual Photo Photo { get; set; }
}


public class Photo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(48)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public virtual Member Owner { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PhotoComment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! That's a really nice, simple solution.  I was very much over-complicating the problem - thanks :)